# accessing unanswered question list faster

Tags: discussion

List of unanswered questions has say, 50 pages. If I want to see what is on page 45,I need to click on multiples of 5 to get to there. Any way faster?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you click the next page, the parameters to the url are displayed. Modify the number in the `page=xx` part to get to the page you want.

```
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?page=45&tab=votes
```